# How can duplicate values be allowed in dictionary when using set

Tags: python

i am using "add" and "set" to enter list as value to a dictionary key. The thing is, my dictionary key is a string. So, i cannot have list as value using "append". Hence, i used "add" and "set" to append to the values. But they will not allow duplicates in the list. How can i change my code to allow duplicates? My part of the code is below:

```
if myKey in myDict.keys():
    myDict[myKey].add(value)
else:  
    myDict[mykey] = set([value])
```

here, value is a float.

For example, if myKey is "abcd" and its value list is [1.5,2.5,3.5,1.5], by using my code above, i can get only ['abcd': 1.5,2.5,3.5]. How can i change the code to allow duplicate values without using append? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have the key be a string and still have the value be a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my dictionary key is a string. So, i cannot have list as value using
>   "append"

That is not so. You can have strings as keys and lists as values:

```
myDict = {}
myDict.setdefault(myKey, []).append(value)
```

The second argument in `myDict.setdefault(myKey, [])` is a default value. If `myKey` is not in `myDict`, the default value is returned.
(Here is a [link to the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).)

Or, you could use a [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections
myDict = collections.defaultdict(list)
myDict[myKey].append(value)
```

Unlike a regular `dict`, if `myDict` is a `defaultdict` then  `myDict[anyKey]` will return an empty list for any key not in `myDict`.

---

Answer (score 1):

You can't store duplicate values in a `set`. That's kind of the whole point.

You also seem to be expecting the `set` to preserve order. It doesn't do that. It may seem to for small cases, but if you write code that depends on it, it will break.

So, what's a type that's kind of like `set`, but allows duplicate values and preserves order? `list`.

The key type does not have anything to do with what value types you can have. Even if it did, it's hard to see why `set` and `list` would act differently. in that case.

So:

```
if myKey in myDict.keys():
    myDict[myKey].append(value)
else:  
    myDict[mykey] = [value]
```

Note that you can simplify the whole thing by using either `setdefault`:

```
myDict.setdefault(myKey, []).append(value)
```

… or by using a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
myDict = defaultdict(list)
# ...
myDict[myKey].append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `defaultdict` with a `list` default_factory

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in [1.5,2.5,3.5,1.5]:
    d['abcd'].append(x)

print d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'abcd': [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 1.5]})
```